# Is there a way to disable GPU scaling in OS X?

Tags: macos, graphics-card

To get better performance, I want to run OS X games at a resolution lower than the native resolution of the notebook. Is there a way to disable the GPU scaling that "stretches" the image into a blurry mess? The result I want to achieve is having a black border around the image.

(I know I can do this with the nVidia drivers in Boot Camp, I just really don't like rebooting just to catch 30 minutes of gaming time, I was hoping there's some obscure way of doing this via defaults write or whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if SwitchResX can help in this case? It provides many more display settings than the system software does, and can change settings on an application-specific basis.

http://www.madrau.com/indexSRX4.html

Answer (score 0):

This kind of setting is usually handled by the application itself, is there a specific game that you're trying to do this with?

Comment: I believe it was Torchlight. Doesn't really matter, I'm not aware of /any/ game that can be told to say run fullscreen at 1440x900 but only render 1280x800 in the middle.